# Web server (httpd): how to update/upload the served content remotely?

Tags: windows, file-upload, apache

Running Apache httpd on Windows, what is the usual method / tool to update / upload the served content from another Windows host? I think of SFTP or SSH, but is there a module for httpd that is alrady ready for that? Thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [webdav](http://www.webdav.org/) for this purpose. Apache already supports it through the [mod_dav module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dav.html).

Windows machine can mount webdav folders directly through "Map Network Drive" option I think.

Comment: Thanks. I'm evaluating this solution, i.e. I'm reading the Apache documentation on how to set up WebDav, and also how to connect with W7 Explorer. Seems "Digest" auth is necessary, but not working for the moment.

Comment: In the end webdav is ok and allow direct edits. FTP over SSL works but no direct edits, and another option would be to use SSH to create a secure channel and use FTP.